# django_auth_ldap - AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP

Tags: django, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I am using django_auth_ldap. Login without checking for a group works fine.

But trying to login with the user `example_user` which was added to the group `example_group` on LDAP and setting `AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP` fails.

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.example.com"
AUTH_LDAP_START_TLS = True

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = ""
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = ""
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("cn=users,dc=example,dc=com",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")



# Set up the basic group parameters.
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("cn=example_group,cn=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
)

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType(name_attr="cn")


AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = "cn=example_group,cn=groups,dc=example,dc=com"
```

From the logs:

```
search_s('cn=users,dc=example,dc=com', 2, '(uid=%(user)s)') returned 1 objects: cn=example_user,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com
cn=example_user,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com is not a member of cn=example_group,cn=groups,dc=example,dc=com
Authentication failed for example_user: user does not satisfy AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP
```

$ ldapsearch -x -h ldap.example.com b"cn=example_group,cn=groups,dc=example,dc=com"

```
ldap_bind: Success (0)
    [...]
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=example_group,cn=groups,dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# example_group, Groups, example.com
dn: cn=example_group,cn=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
cn: example_group
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectclass: orclGroup
description: [...]
displayname: example_group
orclisvisible: true
uniquemember: cn=example_user,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working with the following changes:

**settings.py**

```
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfUniqueNamesType



AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch( "cn=example_group,cn=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
    #ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=orclGroup)"
)

#AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType(name_attr="cn")
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfUniqueNamesType(name_attr="cn")
```